# Textinput changeable value set for React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using TextInput in my React Native app. The problem is i have values already for these textinput fields. But i want to give user option to change the value if they want. But what i have done, the value is fixed and i'm not being able to change the value. Here's my present code:

```js
<TextInput  
    style={{fontSize: 14, borderRadius: 8}}  
    placeholder="William Bennett"  
    value={this.props.user.user.username}
    onBlur={ () => this.onBlurName() }
    onFocus={ () => this.onFocusName() }
    onChangeText={(fullName) => this.setState({fullName})} 
/>
```

Now what can i do to make this value changeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
state = {fullName: this.props.user.user.username}


<TextInput  
    style={{fontSize: 14, borderRadius: 8}}  
    placeholder="William Bennett"  
    value={this.state.fullName}
    .....
    onChangeText={(fullName) => this.setState({fullName})} 
/>
```